# My first experiment with blocks gives me EXC_BAD_ACCESS and I have no idea why

Tags: objective-c, ios, exc-bad-access, objective-c-blocks

-- Hello, just ast the title says. I have a downloader class that I want to use to ..download stuff. I thought I try using a block to notify the caller that the download has finished. The `startWithRequest` method gets called from a singleton class that handles a .net web service. I store the `completionBlock` in an instance variable, and then I call it later when the download finishes. There it gives me `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. I tried retaining `completionBlock` it didn't help. Here is the code:

```
-(void) startWithRequest : (NSURLRequest *) request : (void (^)(NSData *data, NSError *error))_completionBlock {
  completionBlock = _completionBlock;
  if (working) {
    [self cancel];
  }
  working = TRUE;
  canceled = FALSE;

  [Globals ShowNetworkActivity];
  urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest: request delegate: self];
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
  [urlData setLength: 0];
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
  if (!urlData)
  {
    urlData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity: bufferSize];
  }
  [urlData appendData: data];
}

- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
  [Globals HideNetworkActivity];
  self.urlConnection = nil;
  ////////HERE it gives me the error
  if (!canceled) completionBlock(urlData, nil);
  self.urlData = nil;
  working = FALSE;
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
  [Globals HideNetworkActivity];
  self.urlConnection = nil;
  self.urlData = nil;

  if (!canceled) completionBlock(nil, error);
  working = FALSE;
}

-(void) cancel
{
  if (working) {
    canceled = TRUE;
    [urlConnection cancel];
    [Globals HideNetworkActivity];
    self.urlConnection = nil;
    self.urlData = nil;
    working = FALSE;
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: i think you're trying to release some variable that you've already released. Try to run your project with break points and see the problem is in which line.

Comment: I know where it gives me the error (I have just marked the location) but I don't know why.

Comment: im not sure, i dont know exact problem. be sure your connection is not nil in debug before crash?

Comment: It's not the connection, I debugged it step by step, and the error is at the line marked by me.

Comment: I did this way before without blocks, using delegates; and before doing anything with the data, I released my connection in connectionDidFinishLoading and didFailWithError and everything was fine. Here I tried not releasing the connection but it didn't do anything (as expected)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to copy the block, not retain it.

No amount of retaining will save a block that is instantiated on the stack because its storage will disappear as soon as the function it is defined in exits.

```
-(void) startWithRequest : (NSURLRequest *) request : (void (^)(NSData *data, NSError *error))_completionBlock {
    completionBlock = [_completionBlock copy];

// etc
```

Comment: Yes that was the problem. It seems after all the reading I still don't understand this. But at least it works.